# Would you like to add the word "EDITION" to the edited questions

Tags: discussion

There is a frequent situation when we/OP edit the post and the connection with the answers brakes/changes/looks different.

There are questions with more than 10 editions (?!).

My suggestion is if someone make a substantial editing - to write word "EDITION" in the body of the post / at the end with providing new information, or in any other place by addition - "EDITION: what was added/changed etc".

I know that "comments" in edition window are placed, but it is irrelevant to search for them there.

What are your suggestions for the issue?

Comment: I don't think "edition" is the right word, did you mean "addition"?

Comment: @JohnB I meant EDITION as well as ADDITION. There are questions with 10 or more ADDITIONS/EDITIONS which looks like absolutely strange

Comment: I think neither word is correct.. it should be [WeFixedIt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree **some sort of notation** should be added when an edit is made that is more than a simple correction on someone else's answer (or even your own).

All content here on GD.SE can (and almost should) be 'polished' by the community, that includes things like replacing image links with actual images, styling the text and also occasionally adding information that wasn't previously there. I think [HostileFork](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/986/2857) has answered this quite well, any change big enough to render the answers useless should merit a new question instead.

Generally (wish it was always the case!) when the OP is the one editing you'll see things like "Edit:", or "Addendum". Personally, when I make a *significant* edit (even if it's just aesthetics) I usually leave a comment.

Most users more or less familiar with the interface will see the "edited" message when it's someone else editing, I think it's the one when the OP edits that makes things a little less visible and might lead to confusion.

Comment: I don't like "Edit/Addendum" -- the editing should be seamlessly inserted into the post. Readers should not have to complete the construction of the post for themselves.

Comment: I think comments are better. The edit itself is more relevant while the question is active.

Answer (score 2):

One isn't supposed to edit posts so substantially that it breaks a coherence with existing answers.

The best idea is to push back against that tendency, and let them know it's okay to ask a new question... perhaps linking to the first *(and having the first link to the second, as well, probably)*.

Comment: as you can see, the author posted "partial" information http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30052/filling-areas-using-transparent-color-without-affecting-the-border-in-illustrat and after the answer was given, it became clear that the question is more complicated and he asked the new one which was closed. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30054/filling-areas-using-transparent-color-without-affecting-the-border

Comment: @Ilan That particular case just demonstrates someone getting a feel for question editing, versioning, and how to isolate one's questions into discrete units.  There's no need to upgrade the labeling or technology to help navigate such things one doesn't want to have happening in the first place...just improve the education.  Perhaps EDIT when there are answers could have a small warning box saying *"This question already has answers...if your edit would change the meaning of your question so formerly coherent answers would seem confusing or incomplete, consider asking a new question instead"*.